# sending uploaded file and other data , both using one ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, file-upload

I am trying to send the uploaded file and the input text data (there are 5 text fields) without using form action. Is this the correct way to do it, this code works fine if I send only form_data or the values in {} but not both together. This is my code:

```
actionval = document.getElementById('action').value;
titleval = document.getElementById('title').value;
stageval = document.getElementById('stage').value;
substageval = document.getElementById('substage').value;
agentval = document.getElementById('agent').value;

var file_data = $('#uploadFileTrans').prop('files')[0];   
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', file_data);
$.ajax({
    url: "tabs/get_old_contents.php",
    data: {form_data, insert1:actionval, insert2:titleval, insert3:stageval, insert4:substageval, insert5:agentval},                         
    type: 'post',
    complete: function(response){
    alert('Details added successfully!');
            $('#restrans').html(response.responseText);
            // console.log('hey', response.responseText);
            // editor.setValue(response.responseText);
    }
 });
```

and php is this :

```
$action = (isset($_POST['insert1'])?$_POST['insert1']:"");
$title = (isset($_POST['insert2'])?$_POST['insert2']:"");
$stage = (isset($_POST['insert3'])?$_POST['insert3']:"");
$substage = (isset($_POST['insert4'])?$_POST['insert4']:"");
$agent = (isset($_POST['insert5'])?$_POST['insert5']:"");
$date = date("Y/m/d");
```

and this is to upload , it works fine if I have only form_data in data field of ajax

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path);
```

Comment: use the jquery selector like $("#action").val() instead of document.getElementById('action').value; long vanila javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a `FormData` inside an object being sent with AJAX. You need to add the other parameters to the `FormData` object, and use that as the data by itself.

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', file_data);
form_data.append('insert1', actionval);
form_data.append('insert2', titleval);
form_data.append('insert3', stageval);
form_data.append('insert4', substageval);
form_data.append('insert5', agentval);
$.ajax({
  url: "tabs/get_old_contents.php",
  data: form_data,
  processData: false,
  type: 'post',
  complete: function(response) {
    alert('Details added successfully!');
    $('#restrans').html(response.responseText);
    // console.log('hey', response.responseText);
    // editor.setValue(response.responseText);
  }
});
```

Comment: this send the data to php, the way that I mentioned to read in php file, is it the corect way, or do i need to make changes in php code also

Answer (score 1):

You have to add all your data to the FormData object and pass that as the data parameter. Also, set processData to false and contentType to false.

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', file_data);
form_data.append('insert1', actionval);
form_data.append('insert2', titleval);
form_data.append('insert3', stageval);
form_data.append('insert4', substageval);
form_data.append('insert5', agentval);
$.ajax({
    url: "tabs/get_old_contents.php",
    data: form_data,                   
    type: 'post',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    complete: function(response){
            alert('Details added successfully!');
            $('#restrans').html(response.responseText);
            // console.log('hey', response.responseText);
            // editor.setValue(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: I get an error 500 internal server error on jquery.min.js . I checked all the alerts, all variables are correctly received in php file. Can you help me with this, it has been long  with this error :(

Comment: Check your server logs to see what caused the 500 error